# Error code C4 when installing Windows Server 2012 on VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, windows-server-2012

I am getting error code C4 when trying to install Windows Server 2012 on VirtualBox. I was able to install this a few weeks ago. However I had to install a fresh copy again. This time however I always get error C4 no matter what I try.

Settings I'm using:

- 1024 MB base memory
- 2 Processors
- 27Mb video memory
- I have checked to ensure Intel Virtualization Technology (vt-x) is
  enabled in my BIOS.
- Also I have SetExtraData as suggested in [this post](https://4sysops.com/forums/topic/windows-server-2012-r2-on-virtual-box-error-0x000000c4/).

One change I have made to the BIOS since the last successful install was to disable "No eXecute".

Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had disabled "Execute Disabled Bit" in my BIOS in order to install Windows Server 2008 R2 on my VirtualBox.

Re-enabling it seems to have fixed the issue with Windows Server 2012.